# I can't connect the IBAction of UIButton into the ViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

When I try to link the `UIButton` object to the `ViewController` class in order the create an `IBAction`, Xcode doesn't show me the window for creating it. 
I have to say that It only happens with the second `ViewController` of the `NavigationController`, because with the first one it works. 
I believe it should be a Xcode bug...
The situation is the one below:

[image]

Comment: view is added as outlet by default

Comment: where is the UIbutton that you need to connect

Comment: If your button is in the viewController with blue background then you need to connect it with that viewController class

Comment: What classes do you have assigned to your view controllers in the storyboard?

Comment: It's not Xcode bug, you have not set the ViewController class in interface builder. I can tell from the name of VC in Interface Builder that It's controller is Controller finale. If you can't choose the automatically button, then set the vc in attribute inspector.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 8):

In order for CTRL-drag to work, the ViewController must be told which ViewController class to use.

[image: Set view controller class]

Once that is done, you can use split view and Control-drag from the button to the code.  Xcode will not let you Control-drag to the wrong file.

[image: Control-drag in split view]

You cannot control-drag from a button on View Controller 1 to the class file for View Controller 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I see it all in the right way, but you have code for one view controller, which is called ViewController. In this view controller you have an action method for the button via avanti and an action method for the button via indietro. However, the buttons are not in the same scene of your story board. You have the first scene with the button via avanti linked with the ViewController.swift file (Controller initial scene), but the second scene (Controller finale scene) is not linked to your the ViewController.swift file, which it shouldn't. You have to create a new view controller file for every scene in your storyboard and put the action methods in the view controller files that are linked with the appropriate scene. It is also preferable not to call your view controller swift files ViewController.swift, but give them a meaningful name.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: Thank you very much I have solved the problem, It was because I tried to connect the button with the wrong Viewcontroller custom class, so I've done the right separate class for the other ViewController and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the thing you are trying to add is the self.view which is already added in UIViewController Class. try adding another control like button or another UIView